# Cannot automate signing in to Azure Active Directory using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to test logging in to our web application using Azure AD but the click action on the Sign In button doesn't seem to register. Here's the code:

```
namespace WebApp.Tests
{
    using System;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Threading;
    using FluentAssertions;
    using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
    using OpenQA.Selenium;
    using OpenQA.Selenium.IE;
    using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;
    using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

    [TestClass]
    public class LoginTests
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void CanLogin()
        {
            string internetExplorerDriverServerDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
            IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(internetExplorerDriverServerDirectory)
            {
                Url = "https://localhost:44399"
            };

            try
            {
                driver.Manage().Cookies.DeleteAllCookies();

                WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
                wait.Until(d => d.FindElement(By.Id("logonIdentifier")));

                driver.FindElement(By.Id("logonIdentifier")).SendKeys("username");
                driver.FindElement(By.Id("password")).SendKeys("password");   
                driver.FindElement(By.Id("next")).Click();

                wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
                wait.Until(d => d.FindElement(By.ClassName("logo_title")));

                driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("logo_title")).Text.Should().Contain("HELLO!");
            }
            finally
            {
                driver.Close();
                driver.Quit();
                driver.Dispose();
                driver = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the relevant bits of HTML:

```
<div class="entry">
    <div class="entry-item">
        <label for="logonIdentifier">Email Address</label>
        <div class="error itemLevel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
            <p role="alert"></p>
        </div>
        <input type="email" id="logonIdentifier" name="Username or email address" pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&amp;’'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$" placeholder="Email Address" value="" tabindex="1" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
    <div class="entry-item">
        <div class="password-label">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
                <a id="forgotPassword" tabindex="2" href="/redacted">Forgot your password?</a>
        </div>
        <div class="error itemLevel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
            <p role="alert"></p>
        </div>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="Password" placeholder="Password" tabindex="1" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
    <div class="working"></div>
    <div class="buttons">
        <button id="next" tabindex="1">Sign in</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

It all looks OK in the browser: the username and password fields are filled in, the button looks like it gets clicked (the little "working" icon appears briefly above it) but nothing happens.

- I've tried a longer wait (up to 30 seconds) for the home page to
  appear after clicking the Sign In button.

`wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));`

- I've tried sending an `Enter` key while in the form instead of clicking
  the button.

`driver.FindElement(By.Id("password")).SendKeys(Keys.Enter);`

- I've tried executing some JavaScript to call the button click action.

`IJavaScriptExecutor jse = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;`
`jse.ExecuteScript("document.getElementById('next').click();");`

- I've tried using the Chrome and Firefox drivers.
- I've tried on both the local development version and the hosted test    environment.

Nothing so far has worked. There are no error/validation messages shown in the browser during the process.

I'm at a bit of a loss with this one.

Thanks,
Stuart.

Comment: Did you take a look using developer tools while running the Selenium tests? We're doing exactly this in our project and it works. The id we're using is `idSIButton9`

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML

Comment: @rickvdbosch, Yeah, checked the source in developer tools when at a breakpoint. Button has definitely got an ID of next. Edited the question to include the HTML too.

Comment: @StuartWhiteford Update the question with your _code trials_ as well

Answer (score 6):

As of `2019-01-20`, this is working for me:

```
[ClassInitialize]
public static void InitializeClass(TestContext testContext)
{
    var options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.AddArguments("--incognito");
    driver = new ChromeDriver(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), options);
    driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
}

[TestMethod]
public void Login()
{
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://localhost:44399/");
    driver.FindElement(By.Id("i0116")).Clear();
    driver.FindElement(By.Id("i0116")).SendKeys("test@test.onmicrosoft.com");
    driver.FindElement(By.Id("i0116")).SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
    driver.FindElement(By.Id("i0118")).Clear();
    driver.FindElement(By.Id("i0118")).SendKeys("password");
    Thread.Sleep(500);
    driver.FindElement(By.Id("i0118")).SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
    driver.FindElement(By.Id("idSIButton9")).Click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In My Case, My app uses the Azure AD popup Authentication

in my initial case, it was not able to find the elements in the Popup

```
 var userNameField = GetElementAfterWait(By.Id("i0116"));
```

after adding the below code, I am able to access the fields

```
driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles[1]);
```

** GetElementAfterWait this is our private method to get the element after some wait time

```
private static IWebElement GetElementAfterWait(By by, bool isWaitRequired = true)
        {
            if (isWaitRequired)
            {
                WebDriverWait waitForElement = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
             
            }

            return driver.FindElement(by);
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

I have solved the same by using CSS selector as element locator.

SeleniumLibrary.Input              Text                      css:#i0118       your_password

it's working fine in every iteration.